# mongodb GeoJSON coordinates must be an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, geojson

There's a requirement to search some locations in a given region. And here is an example of my test data in mongo:

```
{
"_id" : "insititution_NPqTrcysjKV",
"phone" : "18080808088",
"name" : "Insititution 1",
"address" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"city" : "New York",
"location" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        121.62764, 
        29.89805
    ]
},
"includeLessions" : [ 
    "English"
]
}
```

I've got a list of such entries in my mongodb. and here goes my query in Robo3T:

```
db.Insititution.find(
{
 location: {
   $geoIntersects: {
      $geometry: {
         type: "Polygon" ,
         coordinates: [
           [ [ 121.33, 29.899 ], [ 121.33, 29.770 ], [ 121.67, 29.770 ], [ 121.67, 29.899 ], [ 121.33, 29.899 ] ]
         ]
      }
   }
 }
 }
 )
```

It's works in robo3t, but in my project, I did like this:

```
    var where = {
      location: {
        $geoIntersects: {
          $geometry: {
            type: "Polygon",
            coordinates: [
              [longitudeMin, latitudeMin],
              [longitudeMin, latitudeMax],
              [longitudeMax, latitudeMax],
              [longitudeMax, latitudeMin],
              [longitudeMin, latitudeMin]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return promiseUtils.mongoNativeFindPromise(this.modelName, where);


  // function in promiseUtils:
  exports.mongoNativeFindPromise = async function (modelName, where, options) {
  const db = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
  try {
    let collection = db.db(mongoDBSettings.database);
    var cusor = await collection.collection(modelName).find(where, options);
    return await cusor.toArray();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }
};
```

and this is exactly what the 'where' variable goes like when run the code:
[image]
but mongo return an error:  GeoJSON coordinates must be an array
Can anybody help?

Comment: Compare your polygon with this example: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/index.html#intersects-a-polygon It must be `[[ [longitudeMin, latitudeMin], [longitudeMin, latitudeMax], [longitudeMax, latitudeMax], [longitudeMax, latitudeMin], [longitudeMin, latitudeMin] ]]`

Comment: silly question thx for reply

Comment: It happened the same to me, almost three years later

Answer (score 1):

GeoJSON polygons consist of an **array** of GeoJSON LinearRing coordinate arrays. LinearRing are themselfes array of coordinates.

So you should specify an array of closed lines inside the coordinates array (mind the double array before specifying longitude and latitude):

```js
var where = {
  location: {
    $geoIntersects: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [
          [ // <-- this array
            [longitudeMin, latitudeMin],
            [longitudeMin, latitudeMax],
            [longitudeMax, latitudeMax],
            [longitudeMax, latitudeMin],
            [longitudeMin, latitudeMin]
          ] // <-- and this
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See the [docs for $geoIntersects](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#intersects-a-polygon).